# Discord.js add image attachment

Tags: discord.js

I'm building a Discord Bot with discord.js and trying to add an image as an attachment. I've got some code that processes images, but when I try to send the image, this is what I see

[image]

and when clicking on the link it just send me to "This site can’t be reached"

Here's a snippet of my code

```
  import { createCanvas, loadImage } from "@napi-rs/canvas";
  import { AttachmentBuilder } from "discord.js";
  ...

  client.on(GatewayDispatchEvents.InteractionCreate,
    async ({ data: interaction, api }) => {

    ...
    
    // Return Canvas object
    const allSlices = await generateSliceImages(mapSlices);

    const attachment = new AttachmentBuilder(await allSlices.encode("png"), {
      name: "output.png",
    });

    const message = await api.channels.createMessage(thread.id, {
      content: summary,
      files: [attachment],
    });
```